# Send an Ogre3D object from an RViz panel

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I'm currently working on an RViz panel, from which I would like to send Ogre3D objects (any kind of objects) in the RViz render window, just as [ImuDisplay](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/rviz_plugin_tutorials/html/display_plugin_tutorial.html) tutorial already does.

I think that my problem is I can't get the `scene_manager_` variable from within my panel, since it doesn't inherit from `(rviz::Panel)` – contrary to `rviz::Display` or `rviz::Tool`.

I know that there is a protected attribute named `vis_manager_` in all panel objects – inherited from `rviz::VisualizationManager` class – which has a `getSceneManager()` method, but it doesn't seem to work… (meaning that when I want to add my panel, RViz crashes, without any error code, but just says `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`)

Here's my repo link: [Github repo](https://github.com/Matthieu-5/lpc_plugin_rviz), on Ogre3D branch.

Does anyone have a hint? Does a panel that can send Ogre3D objects already exist? I remain at your disposal for any further information. Thanks a lot!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205290/send-an-ogre3d-object-from-an-rviz-panel/) by [anonymous21729](https://answers.ros.org/users/21729/anonymous21729/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2015-03-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2015-03-18**:
The link to GitHub doesn't seem to work. Just because there is a Segmentation Fault doesn't mean it's rviz related, you'll need to debug it with gdb to know what the issue is: http://www.cprogramming.com/debugging/segfaults.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A guess: in your constructor, you're attempting to do a Qt connect with `_visual`, which isn't created until the `onInitialize` method is called.

---

Originally posted by [kramer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2050/kramer/) with karma: 1470 on 2015-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-03-19**:
@Matthieu_D: please click the checkmark next to the answer of @kramer, so we know that your question has been answered.